# TfIdfVectorizer divides words to single characters?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to find nearest neighbors in a set of descriptions. Descriptions usually contain 1-15 words that I am tokenizing using the scikit's TfIdfVectorizer. Then, with the same vectorizer, I am fitting the base description. However, it seems that the vectorizer divides this one to separate characters, rather than words, because the resulting sparse matrix is of shape [number of letters in the base description x number of unique words in the corpus]

```
descriptions = 'total assets'

products = LoadData('C:/dict.csv', dtype = {'Code': np.str, 'LocalLanguageLabel': np.str})
products = products.fillna({'LocalLanguageLabel':''})

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b')
#tried the below two as well
#vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
#vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b', analyzer = 'word')
dict_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(products['LocalLanguageLabel'])
input_matrix = vectorizer.transform(description)

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
model = NearestNeighbors(metric='euclidean', algorithm='brute')
model.fit(dict_matrix)   

distance, indices = model.kneighbors(input_matrix,n_neighbors = 10)
```

when I print the input_matrix, this is what I get (you can guess that the indices relate to characters in 'totalassets'):

```
print(input_matrix)
(0, 33478)  1.0 #t
(1, 24021)  1.0 #o
(2, 33478)  1.0 #t
(3, 2298)   1.0 #a
(4, 20272)  1.0 #l
(6, 2298)   1.0 #a
(7, 30874)  1.0 #s
(8, 30874)  1.0 #s
(9, 11386)  1.0 #e
(10, 33478) 1.0 #t
(11, 30874) 1.0 #s

<12x39859 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Is that expected? I would expect 10 distances and 10 indices, instead I am getting 12 lists of 10 elements each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, the answer was pretty simple for the amount of time I spent on it. I wrapped the `description` in a list and got the expected 10 results:

```
input_matrix = vectorizer.transform([description])
```